# Where to put non-specific state properties in Redux Toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, reducers, redux-toolkit

I want to use Redux Toolkit, but have global state properties that are not specific to a particular feature, such as "loading" and "errors". These two properties are updated when I make API requests concerning multiple features in my app. Should I put them in their own e.g. API reducer? Thanks

Comment: You can put in a `Shared reducer` which will be shared across app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always better to have separate loading, errors for each api call or each component reducer.
you can think this way, what component is visible to the user at that moment and you want to show loading till the data comes from backend.

You only keep any state global and share when it will be used in another component.